# Applicatin of Stokes' theorem to compute flux of $\nabla \times G$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I need a help on the following exercise:

> Consider the following surface
>
> $$S= \{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4, x^2+y^2 \leq 2, z>0 \}$$
>
> Compute the flux of $\nabla \times G$ exiting from $S$, where $G(x,y,z)=(xy,zx,x^2+y^2)$

---

First of all, it's clear that $S$ can be parametrized with $\sigma(x,y)=(x,y,x^2+y^2)$, where $(x,y) \in B_{\sqrt{2}}(0,0)$. However, that surface integral is not so short to compute, so it's better to use Stokes' theorem and compute $$\int_{\partial S^+} G \cdot dr$$ where $\partial S$ is the boundary of the surface $S$.

The question is: what is the boundary of $S$, or better, how may it be parametrized? My guess is that it is parametrized by $r(t)=(\sqrt{2} \cos(t), \sqrt{2} \sin(t),\sqrt{2})$ with $t \in [0, 2 \pi)$. So, the integral to compute is $$\int_{\partial S} G \cdot dr = \int_0^{2 \pi} (\sin(2t),2 \cos(t),2) \cdot (-\sqrt{2} \sin(t), \sqrt{2} \cos(t),0) dt = \text{computations} = 0$$

Is everything correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note your parametrization is correct. Also note that the surface is above $z \geq \sqrt2$ as $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2, z \gt 0$ so based on your integral, the orientation of the boundary and the surface also matches. But your integral is not zero.

$\displaystyle \int_{C} \vec{G} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_0^{2 \pi} (\sin(2t),2 \cos(t),2) \cdot (-\sqrt{2} \sin(t), \sqrt{2} \cos(t),0) \, dt$

$\displaystyle = 2\sqrt2\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos^2t- \sin^2t \cos t) \, dt = 2 \sqrt2 \, \pi$

By the way the double integral is not very complicated either.

$\nabla \times \vec{G} = (2y-x, -2x, z-x)$. Unit normal vector to the surface is $(\frac{x}{2}, \frac{y}{2}, \frac{z}{2})$

In spherical coordinates $x = 2 \cos \theta \sin \phi, y = 2 \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = 2 \cos \phi$

So your integral becomes,

$8 \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} (cos^2\phi - cos^2 \theta \sin^2\phi - 2 \cos \theta \sin\phi \cos\phi) sin\phi \, d\phi \, d\theta = 2 \sqrt2 \, \pi$

Comment: Thanks for the check, but to compute $\int_S \nabla \times G \cdot n dS$ how did you get that the $\phi$ must lie in $[0,\pi/4]$? I would say that first you draw the plane $(x,z)$, so you see that for $y=0$ you get $x^2+z^2=4$ and hence (since there $x^2=2$) you obtain $(x,z)=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. This corresponds to an angle $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is this correct? @MathLover

Comment: Yes from $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$, we get $z^2 \geq 2$ (as $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2$). So either $z \leq - \sqrt2$ or $z \geq \sqrt2$. We know $z \gt 0$ so $z \geq \sqrt2$ and $z = 2 \cos \phi$.

Comment: Thanks, clear! @MathLover :-)

Comment: I think you're missing a $\sqrt{2}$ in your second component of $G_{| \gamma}$ @MathLover

Comment: @Vefhug I do not see that. It seems ok to me. $\int_C \vec{G} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_C \vec{G(r(t)} \cdot r'(t) \, dt$. Do you mean in $G$ or in $r'(t)$?

Comment: I mean in $G(r(t))$, it should be $(2 \sin(2t),2\sqrt{2} \cos(t),2)$ @MathLover

Comment: No @Vefhug, that is correct. At $z = \sqrt2$, $x^2 + y^2 = 2 \implies r = \sqrt2$. So $x = \sqrt2 \cos t, y = \sqrt2 \sin t$. So $xy = 2 \sin t \cos t = \sin 2t$. Similarly, $xz = \sqrt2 \cos t \times \sqrt2 = 2 \cos t$. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm sorry. Thanks so much @MathLover

Answer (score 0):

the boundary of the surface $S$ is just the two dimentional ball in the xy plane which can be parametarized as $r(t)=(\sqrt{2} cos(t),\sqrt{2} sin(t),0)$ for $t\in [0,2\pi)$

Comment: Why? @YotamMaoz I can't see this

Comment: Well, if we remove the restriction that $z>0$ we just get the 2-sphere $S_{2}(0,0,0)$ and adding the restriction $z>0$ corresponds to slicing the sphere at the plane $z=0$. Now, if $z<0$ there is some distance between the point and $S$ so necessarily $z=0$.

Comment: But $S$ is not lying at $z=0$, right? I think that $S$ is made by the points in the upper semisphere such that $x^2+y^2 \leq 2$, I don't know if I made I explained it clearly @YotamMaoz

Comment: Indeed, your parametrization does not satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, which should be satisfied

Comment: $z$ is not zero. It is a circle in $3D$ parallel to XY plane. If you parametrize as $z=0$, the $y$ component of the vector field will zero which is not correct.